# Does Stopwatch() need to be disposed?

Tags: flutter, dart

By reading the [Stopwatch documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-core/Stopwatch-class.html), it looks like it does not need disposing of. But similar classes like Timer and Ticker do.

I think I have the right answer but because it didn't feel 100% right to me, I just wanted to hear someone else's opinion! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`Timer`  and `Ticker` register callbacks.  If you don't explicitly dispose of them, those callbacks will still be registered somewhere (and therefore will still retain a reference to the `Timer`/`Ticker` objects, preventing them from being garbage collected), and the callbacks will still be invoked eventually if you wait long enough.

`Stopwatch` is completely different.  It's just a convenience class to store a starting time and to compute a time difference.  There are no callbacks involved.  You can just let it be garbage collected.